# CSS3 - Animation-delay not working

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a simple CSS3 animation here.

```
#FadeIn3 {
    animation-delay: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
    animation: FadeIn 3s;
    -webkit-animation: FadeIn 3s;
}
```

I guess I don't have to link the animation itself, because it works perfectly.

Also, the HTML is fine, everything works but the `animation-delay`.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle ? What is your browser ?

Comment: Sure. Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/5PpzR/

Comment: I have exactly the same issue now, changed the order but still doesn't work. Not even @Mr. Alien response. I'm using Chrome 58.0.3029.96

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order is incorrect, you need to place `animation-delay` after `animation` which is shorthand property, and hence it resets the delay timer.

The order of `animation` shorthand is as follows...

[image]
<sup>The order is important within each animation definition: the first value that can be parsed as a `<time>` is assigned to the [`animation-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration), and the second one is assigned to [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).</sup>

<sup>Credits: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)</sup>

---

So, you are defining that after the `animation-delay` property, and thus, `animation` resets the delay to `0`

<kbd><s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cf2h/)</s></kbd> *(Wont work)*

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cf2h/2/)</kbd> *(Switched the order of properties defined)*

> Note: I've minimized the timer to 3s delay so that you can see the
>   effect faster.

---

*Advice*: Always declare prefixed properties before declaring standard ones, so instead of writing like

```
animation-delay: 20s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
```

Have an habit of writing the properties like

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
animation-delay: 20s;
```

Comment: Finally an answer that actually answers the question! Thank you very much